# Getting thumbnail of DBpedia resource with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

This query works:

```
select ?value { 
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Henrik_Ibsen> dbpedia-owl:abstract ?value
 filter langMatches(lang(?value),"en")
}
```

To get the thumbnail I assume I can simply change to dbpedia-own:thumbnail like this:

```
select ?value { 
 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Henrik_Ibsen> dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?value
 filter langMatches(lang(?value),"en")
}
```

But it returns empty value. Both the `dbpedia-owl:abstract` and the `dbpedia-owl:thumbnail` properties exist:
http://dbpedia.org/page/Henrik_Ibsen

Anyone see what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A thumbnail is a *Resource*, identified by a URI. Resources do not have language tags (only *plain Literals* do), so by filtering out all values for `?value` that do not have a language tag `en`, you filter out the thumbnail Resource.